# Extreme Values Vector Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $x^2 +y^2 +z^2$, I need to find the extreme values with the constraints

$x + y + 2z = 0$ and $x^2/25 + y^2/25 + z^2/9 = 1$

I got the following equations using Lagrange multipliers

$2x = λ + μ2x/25$

$2y = λ + μ2y/25$

$2z = 2λ + μ2z/9$

$x + y + 2z = 0$

$x^2/25 + y^2/25 + z^2/9 = 1$

All I'm getting is$ λ = x = y = z = 0$, but thats definitely not right because it doesnt fit the constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2(x-y) = \dfrac{2\mu}{25}(x-y)$. Thus either $x=y$, or $\mu = 25$. If $x = y$, then $x + y + 2z = 0 \to 2x + 2z = 0 \to x = y = -z$, and $x^2/25+ x^2/25 + x^2/9 = 1 \to x = \pm \dfrac{15}{\sqrt{43}}$, and from this we have: $S = 3\left(\dfrac{225}{43}\right) = \dfrac{675}{43} = 15.7$. If $x \neq y \to \mu = 25 \to 2x = \lambda + 2x \to \lambda = 0 \to 2z = 0 + \dfrac{50z}{9} \to z = 0$. So $x = -y$, and $x^2/25 + x^2/25 + 0 = 1 \to 2x^2= 25 \to S = x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2x^2 + 0 = 25$. Thus $S_{min} = 15.7$, and $S_{max} = 25$.